# Error while Starting Server WebSphere

Tags: websphere

I'm making a webService in RAD and websphere. I'm trying to run the proyect but I'm getting this error since the first time I tried to run it.

```
WSVR0221I: application started: ivtApp
SRVE0250I: The Web module PlantsByWebSphere Web Application has been bound to default_host[*:9080,*:80,*:9443].
SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: Default Web Application.
SRVE0250I: Web Module Default Web Application has been bound to default_host [*: 9080, *: 80, *: 9443].
SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: adminconsole redirector.
SRVE0250I: Web Module adminconsole redirector has been bound to admin_host [*: 9060, *: 9043].
WSVR0221I: Application started: DefaultApplication
SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: PlantsByWebSphere Sample Web Application Gallery.
WSVR0221I: Application started: adminconsole
SRVE0250I: Web Module PlantsByWebSphere Sample Gallery Web Application has been bound to default_host [*: 9080, *: 80, *: 9443].
WSVR0221I: Application started: PlantsByWebSphere
TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_1 is listening on host * (IPv4) port 9060.
CHFW0019I: Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundAdmin.
TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_2 is listening on host * (IPv4) port 9080.
CHFW0019I: Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundDefault.
TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_3 is listening on host * (IPv4) port 9043.
CHFW0019I: Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundAdminSecure.
TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_4 is listening on host * (IPv4) port 9443.
CHFW0019I: Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundDefaultSecure.
CHFW0019I: Transport Channel Service has started chain SOAPAcceptorChain1.
CHFW0019I: Transport Channel Service has started chain SOAPAcceptorChain2.
CHFW0019I: Transport Channel Service has started chain SOAPAcceptorChain3.
CHFW0019I: Transport Channel Service has started chain SOAPAcceptorChain4.
SCHD0077I: The Scheduler Service is starting the planners.
SCHD0078I: The Scheduler Service has completed starting the planners.
ADMC0026I: The RMI Connector is available at port 2809
WKSP0023I: Workspace configuration consistency check is enabled.
WSVR0001I: Server server1 open for e-business
SRVE0242I: [transfer]: Initialization successful.
WKSP0023I: Workspace configuration consistency check is enabled.
WKSP0023I: Workspace configuration consistency check is enabled.
WKSP0023I: Workspace configuration consistency check is enabled.
WKSP0023I: Workspace configuration consistency check is enabled.
WKSP0023I: Workspace configuration consistency check is enabled.
at org.apache.soap.server.ServerUtils.readEnvelopeFromInputStream (Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPUtils.extractSoapCall (SOAPUtils.java: 91)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service (SOAPConnector.java: 107)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest (SOAPConnection.java: 55)
at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest (HttpConnection.java: 641)
at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run (HttpConnection.java: 469)
```

I really apreciate your help.

Comment: Is there a way to get an English translated version of the error?

Comment: Sorry I've translated it, I'm not really good at English but I hope it works thaks for your help

Comment: Is that the complete log? That stack trace doesn't start or end with an actual error, so it looks incomplete.